# Question about Types Conformity in C++?

Tags: c++, types

I am reading some C++ text and got the following code:

```
class A { };
class B : public A { };

void main() {
   A* p1 = new B; // B may be larger than A :OK [Line 1]
   B* p2 = new A; // B may be larger than A :Not OK [Line 2]
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I do not understand what the author mean by commenting in Line 1 and Line 2
2. Why can't we do in Line 2?

Comment: In fact, I think that `A` may be larger than `B`, due to empty base class optimization and some strange ABI layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, "larger" is not the key here. The real problem is "is a" relationship.

Any object of `class B` is also of type `class A` (`class B` is also `class A` due to inheritance), so the first line is okay (the pointer to `class A` can just as well point to an object of `class B`), but the inverse is not true (`class A` is not `class B` and might even have no idea of `class B` existence), so the second line won't compile.

Answer (score 7):

The author is showing you that he doesn't understand C++ (or programming in general).  There's no issue of size ("larger") involved.  The issue is that `B` "isA" `A`, so a pointer to `A` can be initialized with a pointer to `B`.  But the reverse is not true.

Comment: There are so many bad C++ books around that I weep for beginners who don't know better.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are silly, really. Object size doesn't have much to do with it. The issue is that you can implicitly upcast pointer types, but not downcast.

BTW, `main` **must** have a return type of `int`. Not `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody here is giving right answers, but I would like to point out what the author means by "larger", etc. 
Consider these two classes:

```
class Animal {
  public:
   bool bIsHungry;
};

class Bird : public Animal {
  public:
    bool bIsFlying;
}
```

Then when I call

```
Animal* animal = new Bird; // B may be larger than A :OK [Line 1]
```

the program allocates enough space to fit variable "bIsHungry" and variable "bIsFlying". (However unless you typecast "animal", you will only be able to access "bIsHungry" even though "bIsFlying" is also reserved for "animal" in the memory.)

When you call

```
Bird* parrot = new Animal; // B may be larger than A :Not OK [Line 2]
```

the program only allocates enough space to fit variable "bIsHungry". Yet the user of "parrot" might want to write code such as

```
if(parrot->bIsFlying)
{   //doSomething()
    ...
}
```

This will not work, because with "new Animal", the program only allocated space for the Animal class, i.e. "bIsHungry" and there was no memory allocated for "bIsFlying". The compiler already "see" that and will "complain", i.e. report an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because B is derived from A, the pointer B* cannot point to A.

Answer (score 0):

`B* p2 = new A;` is invalid because a pointer-to-B may expect `B` to have more information than `A`.

Example:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    int notInA;
};

B* p2 = new A;
p2->notInA = 5; // Wait, which notInA are we talking about?
                // p2 is really an A, and As don't have notInA!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a pointer the pointer value is a memory location. This means that you can set a pointer to point to ANY point in memory. In order to "dereference" that memory and work with the object stored at that point you need to know what kind of object to **expect**.

When B class inherits A class, B will encompass an "A". Sharptooth is correct is saying that there is an "Is-A" relationship. "B" is-an "A", but "A" is not a "B".
The problem would be the exact same in the following code:

```
string* s = new string("");
int a = 44;
s = (string*)&a; //compiler error if not cast
cout << s; // randomness printed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class B : public A { }; 

A* p1 = new B; // B may be larger than A :OK [Line 1]
B* p2 = new A; // B may be larger than A :Not OK [Line 2]
```

> I do not understand what the author mean by commenting in Line 1 and Line 2.
>   Why can't we do in Line 2?

`class B` is derived from `class A`, which - from the perspective of the member variables it contains - means it has everything A has and anything it chooses to add itself.  In your simple code, B hasn't added anything, but if it did have additional data members it would clearly require more memory to store than the simpler `A` type.  If it adds a virtual member function where A had none, the compiler could be expected to add a pointer in B that records the address of the virtual dispatch table listing the addresses of its `virtual` member functions.  The compiler's also free to add padding if it feels like it.

Consequently, the general case is that the size of a derived class is `>=` the size of its base class.

```
A* p1 = new B; // B may be larger than A :OK [Line 1]
```

Here, however much space `B` actually needs is being allocated from the heap/free-store, and the address of that memory stored in `p1`.  If `B` is larger than an `A`, it makes no difference - that's somewhere else anyway - the key thing is that a `B*` is guaranteed to be able to be stored in an `A*`.

```
B* p2 = new A; // B may be larger than A :Not OK [Line 2]
```

Here, a new `A` is being created on the heap, but the programmer is trying to tell the compiler that there's a `B` at that address.  The compiler won't believe it (unless forced) - you'll simply get a compiler time error.  If you do force the compiler (e.g. p2 = (B*)(new A)`) to treat the memory address in`p2`as if it were an`B`, then it may later try to access additional data it expects to be part of any`B`which simply doesn't exist in any`A`: extra data members, virtual dispatch pointers etc..